# In Rails, how to handle multiple checked checkboxes, just split on the , or?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

Curious what the 'rails way' of handling the situation when a user checks multiple checkboxes (with the same name value), and it gets posted back to the controller.

How would you check if multiple items were selected, then splitted on the ID values etc.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The easiest way of doing this is to set those checkboxes up to become an array.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tag_ids[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="tag_ids[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="tag_ids[]" value="3" />
```

Controller:

```
tag_ids = params[:tag_ids]
```

(Of course, you'd probably be using `form_for`-based helpers in the view, and therefore mass-assigning the tag IDs. This is just the most generic example.)

Comment: What happens if the user unselects a checkbox?  Would tag_ids[] be submitted as an empty array?

Comment: @Joe Van Dyk: if no values named `tag_ids[]` are submitted in the HTTP request, then Rails will not think to put `tag_ids` in `params`. You'll have to account for that yourself, e.g., `params[:tag_ids] ||= []`

Comment: To get this HTML, you can do `f.check_box :tag_ids, {multiple: true}, 1, nil`. The `nil` means "without a hidden 0 input". This kind of thing is poorly documented.

Comment: @NathanLong: oh wow, that's spiffy. How would I pass the IDs `[1, 2, 3]` as unchecked but available, like in the example?

Comment: Can someone confirm that `:multiple => true` works in 3.2.11? I can't manage to get `[]` at the end of `name`, so the values don't get submitted as an array at all.

Comment: Just to add to the answer (perhaps there's a better way, but I'm doing this for now): 

I used this method when my model did not have `:tag_ids` as a field, but instead the `:tag_ids` were to populate a join table (user is selecting tags they wish to associate with another model - which is the object the form is based on). 

Under this scenario `f.check_box :tag_ids` with `multiple: true` will not work, but this answer will!

Answer (score 34):

```
f.check_box :tag_ids, {multiple: true}, 1, nil
```

Is the right answer:

Here is the reason, there is a 'multiple: true' option that allows your input to be placed in an array. If there isn't a multiple: true option this will not be allowed.

Comment: I know this is a bit late, but what is the `nil` at the end of this for?

Comment: The nil means "without a hidden 0 input".

Answer (score 10):

Here is an example of view and controller for example where multiple cleaners can be in multiple cities.

```
<%= form_for(@cleaner) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :cities %><br />
    <% for city in City.all %>
      <%= check_box_tag "cleaner[city_ids][]", city.id, @cleaner.cities.include?(city) %>
      <%=h city.name %><br />
    <% end %>
  </p>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And in controller

```
def cleaner_params
  params.require(:cleaner).permit(city_ids: [])
end
```

You can find complete tutorial on "rails way" of doing this https://kolosek.com/rails-join-table/

Comment: Nesha this is the perfect solution. Thank you. You are awesome

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Chuck Callebs answer: When sending an empty string instead of `nil` or `false` as unchecked value, Rails will understand to remove associated ids on an update action:

`<%= f.check_box :tag_ids, {multiple: true}, tag.id, '' %>`

Answer (score -5):

If you want to use a `checked` param you have to write this :

```
check_box_tag "tag_ids[]", 1, true
```

And not this :

```
check_box_tag 'tag_ids[]', 1, true
```

It took me a while to figure out, I hope it will help someone.

Comment: So you're saying that single quotes `'` versus double quotes `"" makes a difference here?