# Multiple Checkboxes, Convert to String, Single DB Column Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, webforms, checkbox

I have a form, that among other things, contains about 20 different checkboxes. Like so:

```
<%= form_for @inventory do |f| %>

<p>
  <%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</p>

...

<p>
  <%= f.check_box :apple %><%= f.label :apple %><br />
  <%= f.check_box :banana %><%= f.label :banana %><br />
  <%= f.check_box :orange %><%= f.label :orange %>
  ...
</p>

...
<% end %>
```

What I want to do is take the value of the selected checkbox, comma delimit them, and save them in a column in the db.  So if the apple and orange checkbox is checked it saves as:

@inventory.fruit = "apple, orange"

how do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think we can send multiple values as a string rather than an array. Look at the below solution

[In Rails, how to handle multiple checked checkboxes, just split on the , or?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425176/in-rails-how-to-handle-multiple-checked-checkboxes-just-split-on-the-or)

The solution is in pure `HTML` code but you can use `check_box_tag` instead.