# How to pass an array or any collection from views to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to pass an array or any collection type from views to controller, but I don't have any idea to how to do it.

Scenario, I have a products resources, in index page 10 products will be listed. Here what I am going to do is that , In same page(index), I want to select some products via checkboxes and selected products will be passed a controller action as a collection to be saved to database with different model.

I thought, I can pass one products via form, Can I use it more than one products, or is it possible to pass JSON from view to controller?

Comment: Put all your checkboxes in a form and submit it.

Comment: Ok but I don't  figure out how to send more than one products data with form, I am newbie, maybe this why I don't understand

Comment: See if this helps... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425176/in-rails-how-to-handle-multiple-checked-checkboxes-just-split-on-the-or

Comment: @HakanKara Did you figure it out yet? You need to add `[]` in your checkbox name.

Comment: Thank you @HarryBomrah , I managed to achieve my goal using  [ ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to select some products via checkboxes and selected products will be passed a controller action as a collection to be saved to database with different model.

Use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Your might have something similar to this

```
$('#some-submit-button').click.function(event){
  var checkedBoxes = $('input:checkbox:checked')
  var json = //format your json however you need with checkedBoxes
  $.ajax({
    url: ('/some_resource_with_different_model'),
    type: 'POST',
    data: json,
    dataType: 'JSON'
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks to point out a way I will try as soon as possible and give a feedback

Comment: Did you find my suggestion helpful? If you did I would appreciate an upvote :)